# Why does the Michaelis-Menten constant decrease in the presence of non-competitive inhibitor?

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics, enzymes

Non-competitive inhibitors don't bind to the active sites of enzymes. However, in the presence of non-competitive inhibitors, the Michaelis-Menten constant is found to decrease. Why is this so?

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong.  In MM kinetics, non-competitive inhibition does not change $K_M$.